Materialized view with Postgresql/Hibernate/Panache
I have created a panache entity in Quarkus which map existing Materialized view. When I execute a refresh view from a test it's not work.
@Entity(name = "MY_VIEW")
@Immutable
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "MyView.refresh", query = "refresh materialized view MY_VIEW")
public class MyView extends PanacheBase {
  public String name;
}

My service:
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyViewService {

private final EntityManager entityManager;

@Inject
public MyViewService(final EntityManager entityManager) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}

@Transactional
void refreshData() {
    Log.debug("Start to refresh data in database");
    entityManager.createNamedQuery("MyView.refresh").executeUpdate();
    entityManager.createNamedQuery("OtherView.refresh").executeUpdate();
    Log.debug("End to refresh data in database");
}}

My Quarkus test:
@Test
void should_test_refresh_view() {
    // GIVEN
    addDataToDataBase();
    myViewService.refreshData();
    assertThat(MyView.count()).isEqualTo(1);
}

My Test fail because count return 0.
Logs show hibernate seems to play refresh:
Hibernate: 
      refresh materialized view My_VIEW
End to refresh data in database
Hibernate: 
      select
         mv1_0.id,
         mv1_0.name
      from
         my_view mv1_0

If I enter in debug mode stop before assertion and play directly in postgresql console the request:
refresh materialized view My_VIEW
The test finished with success and MyView.count() return 1. So, for me it's not a problem with view or postgresql or sql, I think
When I launch the Quarkus dev mode, My code in service work well. The problem appear only on test.
Then I have another materialized view which work well in test mode.
For me it's a strange problem. It seems like Hibernate don't really execute the request.
I try to put thread sleep before assertion, I'm always getting the error count return always 0.
Have you any ideas to help me? Is refresh is a synchronized operation? How to be sure than Hibernate execute request postgresql?
Thanks for your help.
UPDATE
If I enter in debug mode at myViewService.refreshData(); , then execute
refresh materialized view My_VIEW in postgres console, The view MY_VIEW contains data. then  Resume test, when myViewService.refreshData() passed all data in view is removed. The test fail because count return 0
If I execute methode myViewService.refreshData() then I execute refresh materialized view My_VIEW in postgres console, The test finished with success and count return return 1.
I don't know why :/ .
NEW UPDATE
dev-1  | 2024-07-26 20:02:52.488 UTC [360] LOG:  execute <unnamed>: BEGIN
dev-1  | 2024-07-26 20:02:52.636 UTC [360] LOG:  execute <unnamed>: refresh materialized view MY_VIEW
dev-1  | 2024-07-26 20:02:52.646 UTC [360] LOG:  execute <unnamed>: refresh materialized view OTHER_VIEW
dev-1  | 2024-07-26 20:02:52.665 UTC [360] LOG:  execute S_2: COMMIT
dev-1  | 2024-07-26 20:02:52.676 UTC [360] LOG:  execute <unnamed>: select count(*) from my_view mv1_0

So I launch a postgresql with docker compose. When I launch my test  I see refresh request in postgresl log. So I wonder if the problem come from postgresql.
Here the log when I play request from console:
dev-1  | 2024-07-26 20:23:42.177 UTC [30] LOG:  execute <unnamed>: SET extra_float_digits = 3
dev-1  | 2024-07-26 20:23:42.179 UTC [30] LOG:  execute <unnamed>: SET application_name = ''
dev-1  | 2024-07-26 20:23:42.188 UTC [30] LOG:  execute <unnamed>: select version()
dev-1  | 2024-07-26 20:23:42.192 UTC [30] LOG:  execute <unnamed>: SET application_name = 'IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1.4'
dev-1  | 2024-07-26 20:23:42.204 UTC [30] LOG:  execute <unnamed>: SHOW TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL
dev-1  | 2024-07-26 20:23:42.210 UTC [30] LOG:  execute <unnamed>: set search_path = "public"
dev-1  | 2024-07-26 20:23:42.217 UTC [30] LOG:  execute <unnamed>: refresh materialized view MY_VIEW
dev-1  | 2024-07-26 20:23:42.281 UTC [30] LOG:  execute <unnamed>: select current_database() as a, current_schemas(false) as b
dev-1  | 2024-07-26 20:23:42.289 UTC [30] LOG:  execute <unnamed>: SHOW TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL

I don't see difference.
LAST UPDATE
I found this link: PostgresSQL 14 materialized views not updating
I had in test parameters the environment variable -Duser.timezone=UTC and it's work. It seems the timezone is the problem
Is someone can explain why the timezone of JVM impact refresh materialized request?
